# Drag DOM elements into canvas

Tags: html, canvas

Is it possible to drag a DOM element into a canvas and make the canvas react while the element in dragged on top?

For example:

```
<ul>
  <li>ELEMENT 1</li>
  <li>ELEMENT 2</li>
  <li>ELEMENT 3</li>
</ul>
```

Can a user drag one element of this list over the canvas having the canvas "knowing" the event is happening?

Comment: Drag uses event. Just add listeners to the drag events and do what you want when they fire. For more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations

Comment: See [dragEnter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragenter) and [dragLeave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragleave) events. If you need to know about drag movements inside the canvas elements then you can listen for `dragEnter` and then monitor [drag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag) events.